# Generating three instances of one gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object named ball, and on a press of the button "b" I want there to be three of them. These three would be based off where the first ball was. Here is the code in which I am trying to do this.

```
public class TripleBall : MonoBehaviour {

public Ball firstBall;
private int amountOfBalls = 2;
private Ball[] ballArray;
private bool start, avail, located;
void Start () {
    ballArray = new Ball[amountOfBalls - 1];
    start = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < ballArray.Length; i++)
        ballArray[i] = gameObject.AddComponent<Ball>();


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        start = true;
    if (start)
    {
        //Begin locator: Makes it so when the balls spawn they spawn where the first ball
        if (!located) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ballArray.Length; i++)
            {

                ballArray[i].transform.position = firstBall.transform.position;
            }
            located = true;
        }
        //End locator : if statement and loop


    }

}
```

}

I want there, when I click "b" to be three balls on screen. I know they would be in the same position but that is okay. Also, when I say three balls, I mean there will be three after the code is executed. The above code should create two. Here is an image of the ball object from inspector:

[image]

The `Ball` script is the only thing that got cut out of the image.

When I try the code it says the following:

[image]

**Question:** How can I fix this and get the desired three balls to show up. Thanks for any help!

Comment: you are calling RigidBody attached to Tripleball object so check if you have RigidBody attached to TripleBall :) Your picture shows ball object only.

Comment: One un-related problem in your code is `Ball[amountOfBalls - 1];`. That should be `Ball[amountOfBalls];` if you really want amountOfBalls to be amountOfBalls.

Comment: An other problem is that `ballArray[i] = gameObject.AddComponent<Ball>();` just create a new script Ball on your object gameObject(current object) . If you want to duplicate the ball object, you should do this `ballArray[i] = (Ball)Instantiate(firstBall);`

Comment: @Matriac out as an answer, this worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error means that your are calling a RigidBody attached to the TripleBall object but there's no rigidbody on it. When accessing to a RigidBody, you should either check if it is null or be sure there is one on your object.

Your second problem is the array declaration .

```
Ball[amountOfBalls - 1];
```

This will make an array 1 size smaller than amountOfBalls (1 in this case instead of the 2 expected). Just remove the `- 1`

```
Ball[amountOfBalls];
```

And the last problem is that

```
ballArray[i] = gameObject.AddComponent<Ball>();
```

just create a new script Ball on your object gameObject(current object).So your array would all refer to different script but on all the same object. Because you want to have copy of you ball object,you will have to use the Instantiate method. This allow you to instantiate a gameObject from an other object or even a prefabs. Here is how to implement it in your case.

```
ballArray[i] = (Ball)Instantiate(firstBall);
```